# "(stdin)=" MacOS 10.8.5 building Android

Tags: android, macos, stdin

I've been searching around for a solution to this, but I solved nothing.
I'm trying to build Cyanogenmod 10.1 on my Mac (actually once I built perfectly, but now it doesn't, maybe I changed something or some app version).
I encountered this error:

```
    build/core/Makefile:125: *** BUILD_FINGERPRINT cannot contain spaces: "samsung/cm_janice/janice:4.2.2/JDQ39E/(stdin)= 1:userdebug/test-keys".  Stop.
```

I "solved" it by changing ($BUILD_NUMBER) variable with some numbers, but now I'm stuck again in:

```
    /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    /bin/bash: -c: line 0: `echo APK certs list:/Volumes/Android/cm10.1/out/target/product/janice/obj/PACKAGING/apkcerts_intermediates/cm_janice-apkcerts-(stdin)='
     make: *** [/Volumes/Android/cm10.1/out/target/product/janice/obj/PACKAGING/apkcerts_intermediates/cm_janice-apkcerts-(stdin)=] Error 2
     make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs….
```

python version:

```
    Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

gcc version:

```
    gcc (MacPorts gcc46 4.6.4_3) 4.6.4
    Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I have already searched for stdin problems on mac, but honestly I understood quite nothing and I found nothing related to this.
Thank you

NEW: in /build/envsetup.sh there are these lines

```
    if [ `uname` == "Darwin" ]; then
       export BUILD_NUMBER=$((date +%s%N ; echo $CM_BUILD; hostname) | openssl sha1 | cut -c1-10)
   else
       export BUILD_NUMBER=$((date +%s%N ; echo $CM_BUILD; hostname) | sha1sum | cut -c1-10)
   fi
```

So, is there anyone who can tell me why it only shows "(stdin)= 1"?
Which function is giving this problem?

SOLVED
I changed those lines with:

```
   CM_BUILD=$(echo -n $1 | sed -e 's/^cm_//g')
   export BUILD_NUMBER=$((date +%s%N ; echo $CM_BUILD; hostname) | openssl sha1 | sed -e 's/.*=//g; s/ //g' | cut -c1-10)
```

Comment: You should probably figure out where the build number is getting set.  Likely it is trying to capture something about the build environment in a way that only works on linux, and not on osx.

Comment: Build number is not a problem anymore: what I need to find out is why stdin function (function?) doesn't work, what manages it and then how to solve

Comment: This appears to either also be an error in collecting information for the build number, or for another part of the build signature.  I suspect that the appearance of "stdin" in the string is an error resulting from an assumption of a linux platform, and thus a lack of handling of various ways in which osx is different.

Comment: I found out where it is generated: in /build/envsetup.sh there are these lines: if [ `uname` == "Darwin" ]; then
           export BUILD_NUMBER=$((date +%s%N ; echo $CM_BUILD; hostname) | openssl sha1 | cut -c1-10)
       else
           export BUILD_NUMBER=$((date +%s%N ; echo $CM_BUILD; hostname) | sha1sum | cut -c1-10)
       fi